# Identify this font or a good substitute

Tags: fonts

Can anyone identify this font (font used for the title "'Allo 'Allo") or a suitable substitute ?
[image]

Comment: "Listen carefully, I will only say this once." The two sets of LL's are the same, but for the rest all characters are unique, suggesting manual work. Look at Papyrus for similar "hand drawn" shaky lines.

Comment: @Jongware It is useful to remember that designers frequently combine "Caps and Lower" case letters... The answer below proves this one more time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably will enjoy looking at [this pretty nice match](http://www.1001freefonts.com/ragged.font) :)

[image]